# pgrouting how to implement driving directions with php

Tags: pgrouting

I am stuck on implementing driving directions. I have no clue how to do it. I wanted to do it just like this:
[iMaptool LeadDog routing example](http://gis.imaptools.com/routing/leaddog/?zoom=10&lat=33.85667&lon=35.52978&layers=B0TTTF&start=35.492313%2033.826188&stop=35.595811%2033.906827&method=STS&lang=eng)

Please advise

Comment: I don't know much about PGrouting, but your question is a bit hard to follow at the moment. What have you tried already? You can't expect people to guide you through the process from the very beginning

Comment: please expand on the question you are asking or the question will be closed for not being a real question - see FAQ http://gis.stackexchange.com/faq

Answer (score 2):

Thanks, I wrote the iMaptools routing example and I have posted a lot of details to the pgRouting list. You can probably find most of my posts on this in google @ [https://www.google.com/search?q=pgrouting+driving+directions+woodbri](https://www.google.com/search?q=pgrouting%20driving%20directions%20woodbri)

If you have more specific questions post them on the pgRouting list as I do not frequent this board very often.

-Steve